# How do I specify urlconf correctly in Django reverse() function?

Tags: python, django

I need to specify my file containing the URLs explicitly like this:

```py
link = reverse(link, urlconf='backend/urls')
```

backend folder is located in the root of the project.
But the path 'backend/urls is not found, I get an error: *No module named 'backend/urls'*

How do I specify the path correctly?

Comment: I think root is where manage.py is.

Comment: thanks, that's what I thought, but urlconf still doesn't take my url

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I didn't specify it like a module.

`urlconf='backend.urls'` works